# Set default tab in jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a monthly calendar with just basic HTML tables, with each month in a jQuery UI tabs tab.  How can I change which jQuery UI tab is loaded by default?  I want to keep the months in order in the navigation, but have the current month show on page load.

Comment: For jQuery 1.9+, look at @redreinard's answer (most voted).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Update**

The API has changed since my original answer and the release of jQuery 1.9. The preferred approach is to use the `active` option as mentioned in [redreinard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13592031/557445):

```
$('selector').tabs({ active: index });
```

**Older Approach (pre jQuery 1.9)**

According to the [documentation on the JqueryUI Tabs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#method-select), you could set this by using the available `select` function as seen in either the approaches below :

```
// index will be the index of the tab that you wish to select
$('selector').tabs( "select" , index )
$('selector').tabs({ selected: index });
```

Comment: second example is correct. from the docs: `$( ".selector" ).tabs({ selected: 3 });`

Comment: Worked for me. jQuery UI - v1.8.21

Comment: $( ".selector" ).tabs({ active: 1 }); worked for me: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

Answer (score 87):

Please note that this option got renamed in jqueryui 1.9, it is now called "active" (hope this saves someone else the headache I just went through):

```
$('#tabid').tabs({
  active: index
});
```

or

```
$('#tabid').tabs("option", "active", index);
```

See: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

Answer (score 11):

Pay attention that in jQuery UI 1.9 selected changed to active option.
[jQuery UI Documentation (Tabs)](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)

Answer (score 2):

You want [the selected option](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#option-selected) of the tabs.  Note that there's also [a cookie option](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#option-cookie) so that people leaving and returning to your page will have the same tab opened as when they left.

Comment: That page doesn't seem to have what I want.

Comment: Cookie option is deprecied, instead use LocalStorage : activate: function(event, ui) {        
    localStorage.setItem("accIndex", $(this).tabs("option", "active"))
},
active: parseInt(localStorage.getItem("accIndex"))