# How set default opened JQuery UI tab another than first

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have big web application using JQuery UI Tabs. In central JS file I have setted all tabs.

Using

`$("#tabs").tabs;`

But on one page I need to have selected another tab than first.

If I use

`$("#tabs").{ selected: add });`

(name of tab is #add)

Its not running, probably because Tabs are already set up.

Does anyone know how to set opened another than first tab (in default state - after loading page) 
if tabs are already turned on?

I hope, you will understand, my English is pretty terrible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resurrecting an old question, but I couldn't get the example from Andrew to work.

Instead what worked for me, thanks to Rionmonster's second example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565128/set-default-tab-in-jquery-ui-tabs) was:

```
var index = $('#tabs li a').index($('a[href="#add"]').get(0));
$('#tabs').tabs({selected: index});
```

You have to pass the zero-based index as the "selected" option when calling `tabs()`. The first line of the code above gets the zero-based index of the tab for "#add" if you don't know it already.

Answer (score 9):

I know this one's old, but I noticed an error in the code you have written:

```
$("#tabs").{ selected: add });
```

This should be

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ selected: add });
```

Also, `selected` option is deprecated as of jquery ui 1.9 as indicated [**here**](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#removed-selected-option-use-active). Recommended is the `active` option, details [**here**](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)

In any case, use the index of the tab you want to open, not the `href` value; i.e. if you want to open the 3rd tab use

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ selected: 2 });
```

or

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ active: 2 });
```

check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUvvG/)

Answer (score 5):

Use:

`$("#tabs").tabs("select", index)`

Where `index` is the zero-based index of the tab you want to select, or a selector designating the tab you want to open.  So in your case:

`$("#tabs").tabs("select", "#add");`