# Set default focus tab in jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I use `#tabs ul li a:focus` in CSS and its working perfectly. Now, i want the first tab will be automatically focused everytime my web is opened (so the user dont need to click it first).

I have tried `selected` and `active`. Both of them is working, but its not focused.

code example :

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: 0 });
```

The code above will activate the first tab, but its not focused yet.

Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#tabs').tabs("option", "active", 1);
```

or

```
$('#tabs').tabs({active, 1});
```

Read this [Set default tab in jQuery UI Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565128/set-default-tab-in-jquery-ui-tabs)

Comment: Thanks for your help. None of them is working, and i think active, 1 is just another way to say active:1, so its not focused (just selected)

Comment: And for your information, both of your code even make my tab back to its default form (ul, li)

Comment: If there is a solution for this, can anyone post it. I am also trying to set the focus on tab when it is active through jquery.

Answer (score 0):

According to the jquery tabs doucmentation it is as follows:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({active: 1});
```

Notices it is using a colon and not a comma.