# Change <il> tab class after form is submitted

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, tabs

I have a jQuery Tab that looks like this:

```
<div class="tabs">
<ul class="tab-links">
    <li id="aa" class="active"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li id="bb"><a href="#CV">CV</a></li>
    <li id="cc"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

On the contact tab, I have placed an email form, which uses php.
The problem I am facing is the fact that when the form is submitted 
the user gets automatic redirected to the about tab, because this of course 
have a class set to "active".

What I would like is to add the class "active" to the contact < li > and remove it from the about < li > after the form is submitted in order for the user to see the success/error msg being displayed in the contact tab. I have tried following the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776432/changing-jquery-tab-after-submit) tread, by implementing this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $([#contact]).tabs( "option", "active", 3 );});
```

This does not solve the problem..

I am not very experienced with either php or jQuery, so if somebody could point me in the right direction I would be very thankful!

**UPDATE:**

I have added id elements to the < li >, and have tested the code below, the alert msg appear  when the submit button is pressed. But so far I have not figured how to remove and add the class properly.

```
$("form").submit(function(){
  alert("Submitted");
  $('#aa').removeClass('active');
  $('#cc').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: once you submit the form after processing the contact request set a variable in session and when loading the page check the session variable and if exists set the contact tab active and remove session variable

Comment: You have to use ajax for your task. Set the option 'async' to true. 'async' stays for asnchrone, while submit a form is synchrone

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP variable & if condition to accomplish this task.

The following can be a possible solution:

Edit your [your-contact-processing-file].php to the following:

```
<?php
  header("location: your-main-file.php?contact=1");
?>
```

Edit your-main-file.php with the following code:

```
<?php
  // keep this PHP code on the top
  $con = '';

  if(isset($_REQUEST['contact'])){
    if(isset($_REQUEST['contact'] == 1)){
       $con = 1; 
    } else {
       $con = ''; // to avoid PHP error if some other value is passed through contact 
  }
 }
?>

<div class="tabs">
   <ul class="tab-links">
      <li 
          <?php 
               if ($con == '';) echo 'class="active"'; 
          ?>>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#CV">CV</a></li>
      <li 
          <?php 
               if ($con == 1;) echo 'class="active"'; 
          ?>>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Note: it's not a jquery solution but should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer user2661868, unfortunately I have not manage to get your php solution to work. Se my update in the original post!

Comment: Are you getting any error message with the php solution? If you are getting a bug I can help you resolve the issue. At the same time I'll also look for a jquery solution that you are looking for.